# MVC ViewModel containing a dictionary for fields returning empty to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

Attempting to make a Questionnaire page for a client. It's a pretty large list of questions, so I've broken it up into sections and subsections to make it easier for the user to navigate. The problem seems to be that in order to build the page, I iterate over the sections/subsections/questions, and not the answers. Answers are stored in a dictionary, with the key being the ID number of the associated question.

The ViewModel passed to the view is `UserQuestionnaireViewModel`, `QuestionnaireViewModel` has a list of `Sections`, each of which has a list of `SubSections`, each of which has a list of `Questions`. The `Answers` Dictionary gets all Answers linked to the relevant user, indexed by the `Question` they're linked to. Missing Answers are populated here, the View breaks if they're missing.

## Model

```
public class UserQuestionnaireViewModel {
    ClientPortalDbContext db = new ClientPortalDbContext();

    public QuestionnaireViewModel Questionnaire { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Int32, QuestionnaireAnswer> Answers { get; set; }

    public UserQuestionnaireViewModel() { }
    public UserQuestionnaireViewModel(Int32 userID) {
        Questionnaire = new QuestionnaireViewModel();
        Answers = new Dictionary<Int32, QuestionnaireAnswer>();

        List<QuestionnaireAnswer> answerList = db.QuestionnaireAnswers.Where(a => a.UserID == userID).ToList();
        foreach (QuestionnaireAnswer answer in answerList) {
            Answers.Add(answer.QuestionID, answer);
        }
        foreach (QuestionnaireViewModel_Section section in Questionnaire.Sections) {
            foreach (QuestionnaireViewModel_SubSection subsection in section.SubSections) {
                foreach (QuestionnaireQuestion question in subsection.Questions) {
                    if (!Answers.ContainsKey(question.ID)) {
                        Answers.Add(question.ID, new QuestionnaireAnswer() {
                            QuestionID = question.ID,
                            UserID = userID,
                            AnswerBool = false,
                            AnswerText = ""
                        });
}}}}}}
```

The `Section` and `SubSection`classes contain a name string, and a List of whatever comes under them (`SubSection` and `Question` respectively). `Question` has an id int, string for question text, and bools for what fields to show.

## View

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Questionnaire", new { input = Model.Answers })) { %>
    <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken()%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
    <fieldset>
        <ul class="questionnaire-tabs">
            <% Int32 tabIndex = 0; %>
            <% foreach (clientportal.Models.QuestionnaireViewModel_Section section in Model.Questionnaire.Sections) { %>
            <% tabIndex++; %>
            <li id="<%: "tab-button-" + tabIndex.ToString()%>" data-tab="<%: "tab-" + tabIndex.ToString()%>">
                <%: section.Name%>
            </li>
            <% } %>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <% tabIndex = 0; %>
        <% foreach (clientportal.Models.QuestionnaireViewModel_Section section in Model.Questionnaire.Sections) { %>
        <% tabIndex++; %>
        <div class="questionnaire-tab-content" id="<%: "tab-" + tabIndex.ToString()%>">
            <p><%: section.Heading%></p>
            <% foreach (clientportal.Models.QuestionnaireViewModel_SubSection subsection in section.SubSections) { %>
            <h4><%: subsection.Name%></h4>
            <p><%: subsection.Heading%></p>
            <div>
                <table class="questionnaire-table">
                    <% foreach (clientportal.Models.QuestionnaireQuestion question in subsection.Questions) { %>
                    <% clientportal.Models.QuestionnaireAnswer answer = Model.Answers[question.ID]; %>
                    <% if (question.Enabled) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label-col">
                            <%: Html.Label(question.Text) %>
                            <%: Html.Hidden("Model.Answers.Index", question.ID) %>
                            <%: Html.Hidden("Model.Answers[" + question.ID + "].ID", answer.ID) %>
                            <%: Html.Hidden("Model.Answers[" + question.ID + "].QuestionID", answer.QuestionID) %>
                            <%: Html.Hidden("Model.Answers[" + question.ID + "].UserID", answer.UserID) %>
                        </td>
                        <td class="bool-col">
                            <% if (question.ShowCheckBox) { %>
                            <%: Html.CheckBox("Model.Answers[" + question.ID + "].AnswerBool", answer.AnswerBool) %>
                            <% } else { %>
                            <%: Html.Hidden("Model.Answers[" + question.ID + "].AnswerBool", answer.AnswerBool) %>
                            <% } %>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-col">
                            <% if (question.ShowTextBox) { %>
                            <%: Html.TextBox("Model.Answers[" + question.ID + "].AnswerText", answer.AnswerText) %>
                            <% } else { %>
                            <%: Html.Hidden("Model.Answers[" + question.ID + "].AnswerText", answer.AnswerText) %>
                            <% } %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <% } %>
                    <% } %>
                </table>
            </div>
            <% } %>
        </div>
        <% } %>
    </fieldset>
    <h4>Please ensure you have checked all sections of the Questionnaire before saving.</h4>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Answers" />
    <% } %>
</div>
```

On submitting the form, it goes through to the Controller fine (The Controller takes a `Dictionary<Int32, QuestionnaireAnswer>` for this Action), except the model sent through has 0 rows and fails `ModelState.IsValid`

Looking around SO has given me the idea that this is an issue with MVC and Dictionaries in general, or simply failure to bind the dictionary. Any answers in the Database are displayed correctly, it's simply the inability to get the contents of the page back to the controller that's preventing me moving onwards.

Comment: What about using `Html.Hidden("Answers[" + question.ID + "].XXXX`? Remove the `Model.` from the name of hidden elements.

Comment: unrelated to the topic, but if you are using MVC, i suggest you use [Razor Engine](https://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c) instead of [ASPX View Engine](http://www.webdevelopmenthelp.net/2014/10/aspx-view-engine-vs-razor-view-engine.html), its much better

Comment: @RaraituL - I started this project in ASPX out of familiarity and don't have the time/inclination to refactor all the views to Razor, but I agree that it's better.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `foreach` loop. Use `for` loop.
One more thing always use `Html.HiddenFor(model.xxxx)` and for other controls also.

If you use `for` loop along with `HiddenFor` this will automatically create appropriate name for controls

If it's possible to separate out database operation from MVC model then it's best.